# group numerical and factor variables in a data.table

Tags: r, data.table, grouping

I am attempting to group multiple numeric and factor columns of a data.table.
Here is some data:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(Zeit = c(117.9, 118, 118, 118, 118.1, 118.1, 118.2, 118.2, 118.2, 118.3, 118.3), 
                 a = factor(c(15, 15, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 15, 15, 15)), 
                 b = factor(c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)))
```

I am using this function:

```
compr_uniq_data <- function(ecuData) {
  ecuData <- ecuData[, lapply(.SD, function(x) if (is.numeric(x)) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
                   else unlist(unique(x[!is.na(x)]))), by = Zeit]
  return(ecuData)
}

compr_uniq_data(dt)
```

But I am getting the following error:
`Supplied 2 items for column 2 of group 2 which has 3 rows. The RHS length must either be 1 (single values are ok) or match the LHS length exactly. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() explicitly to make this intent clear to readers of your code.`

What am I doing wrong?
If I am doing it with only one factor column it works.

The expected result should look like this:

```
dtres <- data.table(Zeit = c(117.9, 118, 118, 118, 118.1, 118.2, 118.2, 118.3), 
                    a = c(15, 15, 1, 0, 0, 1, 15, 15), 
                    b = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1,  1))
```

Answer (score 1):

The `length` should be the same for a `data.table/data.frame` columns, so either wrap it in a `list` or `paste` them together

```
compr_uniq_data <- function(ecuData) {
  ecuData <- ecuData[, lapply(.SD, function(x)
       if (is.numeric(x)) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
                else list(unique(x[!is.na(x)]))), by = Zeit]
    return(ecuData)
 }

compr_uniq_data(dt)
#   Zeit        a    b
#1: 117.9       15    1
#2: 118.0 15, 1, 0 1, 0
#3: 118.1        0    0
#4: 118.2    1, 15    1
#5: 118.3       15    1
```

#### Update

Based on the comments, we can change the function to take the `unique` of the dataset columns that are not `numeric` as a block and then join `on` with the `numeric` columns if present grouped by 'Zeit'

```
compr_uniq_data <- function(ecuData) {
     i1 <-  ecuData[, unlist(lapply(.SD, is.numeric))]
    
     nm1 <- setdiff(names(ecuData)[!i1], "Zeit")
     
     out1 <- unique(ecuData, by = c(nm1, "Zeit"))
     
     if(any(i1[names(i1) != "Zeit"])) {
          nm2 <- setdiff(names(ecuData)[i1], "Zeit")
          out2 <- ecuData[, lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm = TRUE), 
                 by = Zeit, .SDcols = nm2]
          out1 <- out1[out2, on = .(Zeit)]
     } else {
         out1
     }
    out1

}
```

-testing

```
compr_uniq_data(dt)
#    a b  Zeit
#1: 15 1 117.9
#2: 15 1 118.0
#3:  1 1 118.0
#4:  0 0 118.0
#5:  0 0 118.1
#6:  1 1 118.2
#7: 15 1 118.2
#8: 15 1 118.3
```

---

Or another option is to `replace` the `duplicated` elements with `NA` and then remove those rows having all `NA`s for the columns other than 'Zeit'

```
compr_uniq_data <- function(ecuData) {
  ecuData <- ecuData[, lapply(.SD, function(x)
       if (is.numeric(x)) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
                else replace(x, duplicated(x), NA)), by = Zeit]
  
  ecuData[!ecuData[, Reduce(`&`, lapply(.SD, is.na)),
      .SDcols = setdiff(names(ecuData), 'Zeit')]]
 }


compr_uniq_data(dt)
```

Comment: thank you very much! But there is a small problem. Your first solution of your update is not working as I expected because it duplicates the numeric columns and puts an "i." before every numeric column name.

Comment: is it also possible to interpolate the numeric values instead of using the mean? For example if I want something like Zeit = 117.90, 117.91, 117.92 etc. instead of 117.9, 180, etc. I tried to replace the `mean` function by the approx function, but it didn't work.